# Put dataframe rows in front

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |

I want to take its rows and put them in front like this:

| A | B | A | B | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

Is there any way I can do that?

I tried using iloc but could not figure out how to do this.

Comment: `df.stack().droplevel(0).to_frame().T`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to:

- flatten values as numpy array using `.values` dataframe property and `np.reshape` function
- build a new dataframe, whose column names can be obtained by using `np.tile` on the original column list

```
pd.DataFrame(
    df.values.reshape(1, -1), 
    columns = np.tile(df.columns.values, len(df)).tolist()
)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   A   B   A   B
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```